# Cat has wounds behind his ears

Tags: cats, health, medicines, ears-nose-throat

My cat has wounds behind his ears. There are no good vets that specializes in cats around my area. What should I do?

He is a 2 year old persian.

Here is a photo

[image]

He is an outdoor cat. We also
have other (outdoor) cats here. So far, no personality changes that we notice.
He scratches his ear more than regularly.
It's a fresh wound, sometimes it bleeds a bit due to intense scratching. There are no leaks/fluid but the area looks sore.

Comment: When was the last time the cat had a rabies shot?  How long was that shot good for?

Comment: He had one last year which lasts for only a year.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't look too bad so you don't need to do anything, but keep an eye on it, and if it starts to swell or is getting red, a visit to the vet might be needed. Cats do heal quite fast as long as there is no infection and from your picture it looks like it's starting to heal just fine. You might want to wash the wound with clean water, but this is usually not needed. When the cat washes itself, the saliva does contain antibacterial substances.

Answer (score 3):

**I am NOT a veterinarian, so take my advice with a spoonful of salt.**

What I would do in this situation is try to shave the area (electric hair/beard cutters work fairly well in my experience, just be careful about angling it because a cats skin is thinner than a humans).

I would then clean it using clean water, unless the area looks like it might be infected in which case I'd use medical wound cleaning solution.

If the area looks clearly infected or smells I would immediately go to the vet, no matter the specialisation as the cat will need medical assistance and probably antibiotics.

I'd then cover the area with medical grade cotton and medical tape, or bandaids (The dressing might not work, depending on how tolerant the cat is.), depending on what's available, inspect and change the dressing daily (more often if keeping him indoors is not possible).

And try to keep the cat indoor until it looks healed (especially if the cat does not accept the dressing).